# How do I display multiple doubles and strings in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I am making an IOS Remainder calculator.

I have everything figured out and working for all my operation *except* for the division operator which I want to display the quotient and remainder.

I need to display the quotient, a string that displays remainder, and the actual remainder.

like this:

9/5 =

1 R. 4

If anyone could help me with this it would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just F.Y.I: The swift way:

```
    let result = 9.quotientAndRemainder(dividingBy: 5)
    print (  "\(result.quotient) R. \(result.remainder)")
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
let result = Int(a/b)
let remainder = a % b
let resultedString = "\(result) R \(remainder)"
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the modulo `%` to get the remainder in an integer division is a common error when the divisor is negative. Here is a correct implementation of the extended [Euclidean division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division#Examples) that guarentees that *the remainder is positive and strictly less than the divisor*:

```
func euclideanDivision(dividend: Int, divisor: Int) -> (quotient: Int, remainder: Int) {
    guard divisor != 0 else {
        fatalError("The divisor shouldn't be zero")
    }

    var q = dividend / divisor
    if q * divisor > dividend {
        q += q.signum()
    }
    let r = dividend - (divisor * q)

    return (quotient: q, remainder: r)
}
```

[`signum()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/int/2886673-signum) returns 1 if positive, and -1 if negative.

Here are some test cases:

```
print(euclideanDivision(dividend: 7, divisor: 3))    //(quotient: 2, remainder: 1)
print(euclideanDivision(dividend: 7, divisor: -3))   //(quotient: -2, remainder: 1)
print(euclideanDivision(dividend: -7, divisor: 3))   //(quotient: -3, remainder: 2)
print(euclideanDivision(dividend: -7, divisor: -3))  //(quotient: 3, remainder: 2)
print(euclideanDivision(dividend: 0, divisor: -3))   //(quotient: 0, remainder: 0)
print(euclideanDivision(dividend: 1, divisor: 3))   //(quotient: 0, remainder: 1)
print(euclideanDivision(dividend: -1, divisor: 3))  //(quotient: 0, remainder: -1)
print(euclideanDivision(dividend: 1, divisor: -3))   //(quotient: 0, remainder: 1)
print(euclideanDivision(dividend: -1, divisor: -3))  //(quotient: 0, remainder: -1)
euclideanDivision(dividend: -7, divisor: 0)          //Fatal error: The divisor shouldn't be zero
```

You could format the result into a string:

```
let division = euclideanDivision(dividend: 9, divisor: 5)
let quotient = division.quotient
let remainder = division.remainder

print(String(quotient) + " R. " + String(remainder))   //"1 R. 4"
```